# Amazon device messaging and A3L implementation is not working

Tags: android, kotlin, amazon-device-messaging

I have setup my project for Amazon fireTv and for notification purpose I used Amazon device messaging A3L service

But my onMessageReceived is not getting triggered this is not helping to hit onMessageReceived so that I can get the hit of notification and can fetch data from that notification

Amazon device messaging and A3L implementation is not working

```
import android.content.Context
import android.util.Log
import com.amazon.A3L.messaging.A3LMessagingService
import com.amazon.A3L.messaging.RemoteMessage

class   MyA3LMessagingService :A3LMessagingService() {
    override fun onMessageReceived(context: Context?, remoteMessage: RemoteMessage?) {

        Log.d("notification","${remoteMessage!!.notification}")
        val data: Map<String, String> = remoteMessage.data
        for (key in data.keys) {
            
        }
    }

    override fun onNewToken(p0: Context?, p1: String?) {
    }
}
```

I have setup my project for Amazon fireTv and for notification purpose I used Amazon device messaging A3L service

but my onMessageReceived is not getting triggeredthis is not helping to hit onMessageReceived so that I can get the hit of notification and can fetch data from that notification

```
import android.content.Context
import android.util.Log
import com.amazon.A3L.messaging.A3LMessagingService
import com.amazon.A3L.messaging.RemoteMessage

class   MyA3LMessagingService :A3LMessagingService() {
    override fun onMessageReceived(context: Context?, remoteMessage: RemoteMessage?) {

        Log.d("notification","${remoteMessage!!.notification}")
        val data: Map<String, String> = remoteMessage.data
        for (key in data.keys) {
            
        }
    }

    override fun onNewToken(p0: Context?, p1: String?) {
    }
}




class SplashActivity : FragmentActivity() {

    lateinit var binding: ActivitySplashBinding
    val loginViewModel: LoginViewModel by viewModels()
    var handle = Handler()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivitySplashBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        mamotoHit(Const.m_App, "Start","")

        val deviceId = deviceId()
        SharedPreference.instance!!.putString(Const.DEVICE_ID, deviceId)
        val versionCode = version()
        SharedPreference.instance!!.putString(Const.VERSION, versionCode)
        val currentPlatForm = A3LMessaging.getCurrentPlatform(baseContext)

        if (currentPlatForm.equals(A3LMessagingConstants.ADM_PLATFORM, true)) {
            A3LMessaging.getToken()
                .addOnCompleteListener { task: Task<String> ->
                    if (!task.isSuccessful) {
                        task.exception!!.printStackTrace()
                        return@addOnCompleteListener
                    }
                    val device_token = task.result
                    SharedPreference.instance!!.putString(Const.DEVICE_TOKEN, device_token)
                }
        } else if (currentPlatForm.equals(A3LMessagingConstants.FCM_PLATFORM, true)) {
            FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token.addOnCompleteListener { task: Task<String> ->
                if (!task.isSuccessful) {
                    task.exception!!.printStackTrace()
                    return@addOnCompleteListener
                }
                val device_token = task.result
                SharedPreference.instance!!.putString(Const.DEVICE_TOKEN, device_token)
            }
        }

        setobservers()


    }
```

Amazon device messaging and A3L implementation is not working